# PHP sqlserv - problems executing stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I am trying to pass parameters to a stored procedure
The stored procedure executes fine within management studio, however after trying numerous variations on the code below.

Error Returned:

FAILED!Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. ) )

```html
<?php
include("connection.php");

$clerk_name1 = ''; $clerk_name2 = ''; $order1 = ''; $order2 = ''; $part1 = ''; $part2 = ''; $customer1 = ''; $customer2 = ''; $date_from = ''; $date_to = '';  

if (!empty($_REQUEST['clerk_name1']) && !empty($_REQUEST['clerk_name2']) && !empty($_REQUEST['order1']) && !empty($_REQUEST['order2']) && !empty($_REQUEST['part1']) && !empty($_REQUEST['part2']) && !empty($_REQUEST['customer1']) && !empty($_REQUEST['customer2']) && !empty($_REQUEST['date_from']) && !empty($_REQUEST['date_to']))

$sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON; {CALL sp_order_activities (@clerk_name1 = ?, @clerk_name2 = ?, @order1 = ?, @order2  = ?, @part1 = ?, @part2 = ?, @customer1 = ?, @customer2 = ?, @date_from = ?, @date_to = ?)}";

$clerk_name1 = $_GET['clerk_name1']; $clerk_name2 = $_GET['clerk_name2']; $order1 = $_GET['order1'];
$order2 = $_GET['order2'];$part1 = $_GET['part1'];
$part2 = $_GET['part2']; $customer1 = $_GET['customer1'];
$customer2 = $_GET['customer2'];$date_from = $_GET['date_from'];
$date_to = $_GET['date_to'];

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, [
    [$clerk_name1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$clerk_name2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$order1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$order2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$part1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$part2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$customer1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$customer2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$date_from, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$date_to, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN]
]);
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "execute FAILED!";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$data = [];
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){

 $data[] = $row;
 
}

echo json_encode($data);
ob_flush();
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the PHP user has rights to execute stored procedures?

Comment: yup - I'm running very similar code on the same database with no issues

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "execute FAILED!";

Comment: yes I can see it might run that code, but simply seeing "execute Failed" is useless - you made that phrase up and it occurs on every kind of error. It doesn't tell us what's actually wrong. Call [sqlsrv_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) to get technical details of the error which might help you to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Try `die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));` instead of just `die();`

Comment: I'll pop that in now -

Comment: FAILED!Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. ) )

Comment: ok so now you need to check what's actually in the parameters when you call the procedure, and check they're what you expected, and that they're values that SQL Server will understand (e.g. if it's a date, make sure it's in a format that SQL can parse)

Comment: I'll double check -

Comment: @EdwardDoyle Please can you [edit] the question to include the full details of the error, so that people don't need to read through the comments to find crucial details about the problem. Also, make sure you check that the `sqlsrv_prepare` call is succeeding before running `sqlsrv_execute`.

Comment: @ADyson - the date seems to be the issue - I'll look at the JavaScript again

Comment: using an unambiguous format such as yyyy-mm-dd would be safest